# Matlab - datetick, datenum issues

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a bunch of data that are 2 min averages and I want to have the label on the xaxis show day/month hour:mins. I can get some dates to show up on the xaxis but there are a few problems:

1. location of xticks does not coincide with my data (see code snippet)
2. in my real data i have +1000 points so i would like to label in certain time intervals, say every 12hrs.

below is a sample.
any help would be greatly welcome.

```
%make date vec
ds = {'28/01/2000 11:52:00';'28/01/2000 11:54:00';'28/01/2000 11:56:00'};
x = datenum(ds,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')

y = [1,2,3]; %data
plot (x,y,'x')

%define start and end date for xAxis
startDate = x(1)
endDate = x(end)
xdata = linspace(startDate,endDate,5)
set(gca,'XTick',xdata)
datetick('x','dd/yy HH:MM')
```

Comment: dd/yy seems like a very odd format to use.

Comment: Yup it sure is but I'm trying to save some space on the xaxis. Its a homework assignment, so its ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `keepticks` to the `datetick` call. Fixed things up here on my R2012a:

```
datetick('x','dd/yy HH:MM','keepticks')
```

Source: [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309354) and [datetick doc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html)

Comment: Thanks! this worked great on the example code I put up but when I applied it to my large dataset, the time is shifted. My data should be Jan and the dates start in Aug. 

I applied Dan's solution (above) and it worked on the large dataset but the ticks did not match up on the example code.

Comment: I suggest on beforehand already setting the xlimits with `xlim` and xticks as you already do. When you use @Dan's solution, it is static, no zooming are anything or everything is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is instead of using `datetick()` set the ticklabels your self. So replace your last line of code with these two lines:

```
    dsdata = datestr(xdata, 'dd/yy HH:MM');
    set(gca,'XTickLabel',dsdata);
```

Comment: edit - darn on my big dataset, it only shows the first 7 time stamps on the xaxis. any suggestions on how to get the time right?

Comment: did you check if dsdates contains the right information? And xdata for that matter. Maybe they only have 7 elements in them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me to get ticks every minute

```
    step=2.5/3600;  % minute
    debut = (floor(pts_dthgps(1)/step))*step;
    fin = (floor(pts_dthgps(sz)/step))*step;
    figure(2);
    h=plot(pts_dthgps, pts_vitgps);
    set(gca, 'XTick', [debut:step:fin]);
    datetick('x','HH:MM','keeplimits','keepticks');
```